# Getting an element using jquery with similar class names

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, element

I have a 2 div tags which a similar class names, the only difference is that the second div has an extended class name. How can I retrieve the 2 elements seperately in 2 different variables using jquery.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='submit'></div>
  <div class='submit newClass'></div>
</div>
```

From the above example I need the item which has the class `'submit'` and not `'submit newClass'`.

If i did `$('div.container .submit')`, this gives me both the div tags. How can i acheive this. I would not like to use index based selections or by using the `'first'` method in jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the second `div` does not really have an "extended class name" as you put it, it has two separate classes, `submit` and `newClass`. If that's the case, you can exclude elements matching `.newClass` from your selection using the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
var elements = $(".submit:not(.newClass)");
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
var elements = $(".submit").not(".newClass");
```

If on the other hand your example is wrong and you do actually have an longer class name that starts with "submit", you can use the "[contains word](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)" selector:

```
var elements = $("[class~=submit]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with the class you don't want:

```
 $('div.container .submit:not(.newClass)')
```